# Return Exception message in JSON format

Tags: c#, wcf, faultcontract

I am working on `WCF` application which is running fine in production. It has lots of service methods. Now there is requirement that if one of the field in config file is set to `true` then it must show some custom message to consumer.

I created constructor to make sure it will be called for each request and checked for that config key there and thrown `FaultException` as below

```
public RESTService()
{
    if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("BlockLogin") == "1")
        throw new FaultException("Application under maintainance");
}
```

but it is not giving response in `JSON`. Instead it returns it in `html` format as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Request Error</title>
        <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
            <p xmlns="">The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the 
                <a rel="help-page" href="http://172.16.3.156:81/_RestAPI/RESTService.svc/help">service help page</a> for constructing valid requests to the service.
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think, that using `Exception` in current situation is a good idea. There is nothing exceptional happening, you're just want to notify user that application under maintenance. Just create an error response.

Comment: @SeM How can I do that? Is contructor idea correct?

Comment: @Imad please refer this <https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2520d18d-692d-4d73-afc7-2831bbfa189c/returing-custom-json-message-from-exception-in-rest-wcf-service?forum=wcf>

Comment: You said in your question that this project is `WPF`, but tagget `WCF`, so is it one or both?

Comment: @SeM sorry it's WCF only. I will update

Comment: @AshishKamble I thought of that first but I will end up modifying all operations and it will be too time consuming. That would be my last solution

Comment: @Imad Yes true but we like to build enough flexible software for future modification, Right

Comment: I've not done wcf projects for a while now, but take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230160/turn-off-wcf-soap-service-for-maintenance-and-provide-friendly-message). If you use throwing exception behavior, your clients should be aware of that and be ready to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use exception - as you saw WCF will convert it to a 500 server error, and not give you control.

You could create a class (plain class) called (for example) BusinessFault:

```
public class BusinessFault
{
 public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
 public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when you would like to return a fault:

```
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("BlockLogin") == "1")
{
  return new BusinessFault() {
    ErrorCode = "0001",
    ErrorMessage = "Application under maintainance"
  }
}
```

Comment: Then you return it as you normally would return an object to the consumer. Note this still returns an HTTP error code of 200.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I implement it in a way that it should get automatically called when service is requested. I want to keep all operations as it is, if possible.